# Reading from multiple child processes with pipe()?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a chunk of code where I am trying to split a problem into *N* subproblems across *N* child processes, having each process do work with its given subproblem, then merging the results back together via piping.

The size of each subproblem's solution is know ahead of time, in the form of an int array.

The issue appears to be that the subproblem solutions are not being read in by the main process. Trying to access the read in data afterwards gives a `NULL pointer error`. I think the cause may be due to the exiting of child processes before the data is read in, but I have been unable to verify this in my own experimentation.

The code I am using looks roughly like this

```
  int** child_pipes = init_child_pipes(process_cnt);
  int* solution_sizes = get_solution_sizes(...);
  pid_t children[process_cnt];
  for (int i = 0; i < process_cnt; i++) {
    if ((children[i] = fork()) == 0) {
      // close all unused pipes for this child process
      for (int j = 1; j < process_cnt; j++) {
        close(child_pipes[j][0]); 
        if (i != j)
          close(child_pipes[j][1]);
      }

      int* solution = do_subproblem(...)
      int c = write(child_pipes[i][1], solution, solution_sizes[i]);
      close(child_pipes[i][1]);
      exit(0); // exit so no loop
    }
    else if (children[i] < 0) { // child < 0
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create child processes");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  // wait on children
  int status;
  for (int i = 0; i < process_cnt; i++) 
    waitpid(children[i], &status, 0);

  // merge cells
  int** all_subproblems = malloc(sizeof(int*) * process_cnt);
  for (int i = 0; i < process_cnt; i++) {
    close(child_pipes[i][1]); // close writing end
    read(child_pipes[i][0], &all_subproblems[i], solution_sizes[i]);
    close(child_pipes[i][0]); // close read end
  }
```

I am not sure if I am using `fork()` and `pipe()` incorrectly here, but that certainly may well be the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `all_subproblems[i]`.

Comment: Why do you start all your loops from `1`? Array indexes start at `0`.

Comment: Should `subproblem_sizes` be `solution_sizes`?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for pointing out those obvious typos, I think the issue may simply be the allocation of `all_subproblems[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for each element of `all_subproblems` to point to.

Use `malloc()` to allocate this memory. And the argument to `read()` should be the array element, not the address of the array element.

```
  // merge cells
  int** all_subproblems = malloc(sizeof(int*) * process_cnt);
  for (int i = 1; i < process_cnt; i++) {
    close(child_pipes[i][1]); // close writing end
    all_subproblems[i] = malloc(subproblem_sizes[i]);
    read(child_pipes[i][0], all_subproblems[i], subproblem_sizes[i]);
    close(child_pipes[i][0]); // close read end
  }
```